# Visual Studio 2017 suddenly will not upload new JavaScript files to Azure

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with a bunch of TypeScript files. I use Gulp to minify and bundle them, but I also upload the generated JavaScript files to some environments to make it easier to debug.

I publish to Azure from Visual Studio 2017 using Project > Publish, using the App Service publish target.

For some reason, the generated JavaScript files from **newly added** TypeScript files are not being uploaded (the generated JavaScript from older TypeScript files continues to be uploaded just fine).

These JavaScript files are not actually included in my project (they're just sitting in the folder, next to their TypeScript parents, where they are generated).

I don't see anywhere within the project file where I'm actually specifying that they should be uploaded. However, if I delete one of the older files from the server using Cloud Explorer and republish, **the older JavaScript files are published again, while my new ones are ignored.**

What on earth could be causing this?

Comment: If you're using Full Framework .NET, you need to add every file that you want published to your project (or else use a wild card include in your project to include every file in a directory). One way or another, your project needs to know about the file. I have a similar build/deploy system where my JS is generated at build time, and I keep around "placeholder" files referenced in the project, so the project knows they exist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cleaned the project and re-published, and it started working correctly again with no changes. In case anyone has the issue, one quirk prevented me from finding this earlier: My build mode was set to Debug, but I was publishing a Release build. When I cleaned the project, I presumed it would clean everything, but actually, it only cleaned Debug. When I set the project to Release and cleaned, it properly cleaned the obj\Release directory, and when I re-published after that, the files (still not referenced in the actual project) made it to the server. Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, you want to allow your JS files in specify folder would be uploaded to Azure web app, to achieve this, we need to set our `.csproj` file.

For example, we can do as below that upload all files in "Resource" folder to azure web app when we publish our project:

```
<Content Include="Resource\*">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</Content>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This does indeed seem to work. It also did some weird things to my project, like creating duplicate items (multiple references to the same file -- one being the existing TypeScript file that was part of the project, and one being a duplicate reference brought in, I presume, by the CopyToPublishDirectory directive). I think this would have been solved by just deleting one of each duplicate, but I didn't have to test that because I found that simply cleaning both Debug and Release modes and re-publishing fixed the issue (see comment in original question).

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue and I fixed it by:

1. Closed Visual Studio project
2. Removed all but the latest folder in this location: 
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`
3. Reopened Visual Studio project
4. In the directory that contained the TypeScript file that would not publish, I added a brand new TypeScript file called `Foo.ts` with dummy content. 
   *(It prompted me to **update my Typescript Plugin to the current version**, which I accepted)*
5. I verified that `Foo.ts` compiled to javascript when the project built.

At that point, **publishing my project would now deploy all generated JavaScript files**, so I deleted the dummy Foo.ts since it was no longer needed.

I hope this helps someone solve this.